# Sticky floating action button hidden behind other component in Quasar

Tags: css, vue.js, quasar-framework

So I created simple floating action button which I placed on the top right corner of the page.
When scrolling down the button is sticking to that top right place as expected, except when there is another component it hidees below it -sometimes below the text or below card and is unclickable.

Is there a way to make it stick on top of anything that it goes over?

Here - [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-bas-z50d3?file=/src/pages/Index.vue) - you can see the reproduction code and the behaviour of the button when you scroll down.

Answer (score 4):

Just specifying the appropriate `z-index` to `q-page-sticky` element resolves the problem.

```
<q-page-sticky position="top-right" :offset="[10, 10]" style="z-index: 3">
```

Better than using style attribute, create a class and add the CSS therein. Regards.

Comment: Can use the Quasar class...  `class="z-top"`

Answer (score 1):

You can also put q-page-sticky as the last item in your q-page. That is what the docs recommend. I am assuming that z-index increments for each element automatically.

I like `class="z-top"` much better as it lets me put the sticky at the top in the template if it will be at the top of the page.